# How to make POST request to an API with SCRAPY

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, http-post

I wanted to know the method which you are using to make a `POST` request to an `API` using `SCRAPY`.

Please bear with me if you think this question is not in standards of Stackoverflow.

Your help is appreciated.

I was scraping a website that shows data with the API but unfortunately, I can't scrape it.

Website: https://www.sla.org.sg/hive/sla/membershipDirectory

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to yield a `FormRequest`, the body of the request should go into `formdata` parameter. [Read more here.](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#formrequest-objects)
Something like this:

```
api_url =  'https://www.sla.org.sg/hive/sla/membershipDirectory/search'
sample_form = {
   'field1': 'value1',
   'field2': 'value2',
}
yield FormRequest(url=api_url, formdata=sample_form, callback=your_parsing_method)
```

Comment: there is not form data, instead, there is a "Request Payload"

Comment: `fomdata` is the name of the argument of the `FormRequest` method. In this argument you pass the form that compose the POST body, the payload. [More on POST requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)